# Fair Use Quoting Reviews in Videos

Tags: copyright, fair-use

If I am making a video about a particular business, is it fair use to, within that video, quote a review or rating from Google or Yelp?  i.e. Such and Such business has a 5 star rating from Jackie Joe Jim Bob on Yelp!  They said, "This business is totally radtastic!  We Love it!"

And while the presenter says that, the quote would be printed on the screen.  Is this ok?

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much exactly what the concept of "fair use" was invented for. The only thing that would be even more to the purpose is quoting and criticizing a politician's speech.

Comment: So are there any particular situations where this would not be ok?  Like if the video was a sponsored video would that matter? I.e.

Comment: Well, there could be TOS conditions on what you can post on some venue, but typically they simply say "don't infringe someone else's copyright with stuff you put here". However, you could run afoul of a rule that you can't mention brand X on channel Y.